# Filter an array of strings from another array of strings in javascript (this is not a duplicate)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array: `['Bobby', 'John', 'Sam']`, and another simply `['Bobby', 'John']`. I want to filter The second array from the first, leaving only `Sam`. I'm trying to achieve this with `filter`.

Comment: Please don't ask duplicate questions, it really degrades the site. If you get no answer - put up a bounty or something similar to attract attention.

Comment: Apologies man, at least it worked :)

Comment: where is the bounty button? can't really find it.

Comment: `const filtered = a.filter(name => b.indexOf(name) < 0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)method  with [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method:

```js
var a = ['Bobby', 'John', 'Sam'],
  b = ['Bobby', 'John'];

var res = a.filter(function(v) {
  return b.indexOf(v) == -1;
  // or in latest browser
  // return !b.includes(v);
})

console.log(res);
```

This works because `Array#filter` takes a callback that is a predicate, and filters elements of an array based on that callback. If the callback returns true, the element is kept, otherwise it is filtered out. Per the documentation:

> **`callback`**
>
> Function is a predicate, to test each element of the array. Return true to keep the element, false otherwise

In the snippet above, `v` holds the value for the current value being processed in the array. The code then goes through the `a` array, returning true or false based on if that element (`v`) appears in `b`, with `Array#indexOf`.

Since `Array#indexOf` returns -1 if the element *does not* exist in the array, the callback checks to see if `v` does not exist in `b`. If it does not, filter it out, thus giving the desired result.

Comment: I've added some additions which may have been excessive. Rollback as you wish :^)